# Composer Vendor Directory : Accessing magento classes from Vendor directory

Tags: magento-1.9, composer, autoloader

I have installed a magento module called [Mage-Resque](https://github.com/ajbonner/mage-resque) using composer. Composer has installed all the components into a directory called **Vendor**. When I run the module, one of the component needs to access the class `Mns_Resque_Model_Job_Logmessage`. But it always returns error **Class not found**.

As per my understanding the codes in Vendor directory cannot access the Namespace of Magento. How can I solve this issue should I something additional config in `composor.json` file.

**EDIT**

Here is the error message that I get

```
Could not find job class Mns_Resque_Model_Job_Logmessage
backtrace : vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Resque/Job.php(172): Resque_Job_Factory->create('Mns_Resque_Mode...', Array, 'default')\",\"#1 //vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Resque/Job.php(189): Resque_Job->getInstance()\",\"#2 //vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Resque/Worker.php(240): Resque_Job->perform()\",\"#3 //vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Resque/Worker.php(202): Resque_Worker->perform(Object(Resque_Job))\",\"#4 //vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/bin/resque(127): Resque_Worker->work(5, false)
```

**EDIT**

When I searched I found that the check ie the check for to whether class exists happens in following path `vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Resque/Job/Factory.php`. But the model class is in `app/code/community/Mns/Resque/Model/Job/Logmessage.php`.

**Composer.json**

```
{

    "require": {
        "ajbonner/mage-resque": "*",
        "magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "aoepeople/aoe_profiler": "*",
        "magetest/magento-phpunit-extension": "*"
    },
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/ajbonner/magento-composer-autoload"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/ajbonner/mage-resque"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/MageTest/Mage-Test"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_Profiler"
    }
    ],
    "extra":{
        "magento-root-dir": "./",
        "magento-deploystrategy":"copy" 
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "shell"
    }
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

To test I have created a controller action from which I'm queuing a job. The job seems to be getting queued in Redis server but then it results in above error.

Here is the code in controller action I'm using (Please note that this is code I copied from GitHub page for Mage Resque)

```
$resque = Mage::getSingleton('mnsresque/factory')->create();
$resque->addJob(
    'Mns_Resque_Model_Job_Logmessage',
    array('message'=>'foo'));
```

As per the error log the error occurs in the following file

```
vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Resque/Job/Factory.php:16
```

Which is outside of the Magento `app/` folder structure. And following is the code that causes this error.

```
if (!class_exists($className)) {
            throw new Resque_Exception(
                'Could not find job class ' . $className . '.'
            );
        }
```

The class above code trying to access is defined in `app/code/local/community/Mns/Resque/Model/Job/`. I have also tried copying the entire folder Mns to `/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Resque/Job/` thinking that the `class_exists` checks in the current folder. But that too is not working.

How I can resolve this issue. Have i missed something?

Comment: Are you sure it's Magento 1.9?

Comment: Yes... When i searched i found that the check ie the check for to whether class exists happens in following path vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Resque/Job/Factory.php. But the model class is in app/code/community/Mns/Resque/Model/Job/Logmessage.php.

Comment: "As per my understanding the codes in Vendor directory cannot access the Namespace of Magento" - No. Or does the module run some scripts outside the context of Magento? Then you would need to initialize the `Varien_Autoload` autoloader, because the composer autoloader does not load classes from Magento modules. Can you share your code? Another possibility is that `Mns_Resque_Model_Job_Logmessage` cannot be found because the file is not readable.

Comment: Hi i have edited the question and added some codes. Please let me know if that is enough.

Answer (score 3):

This has to work, the issue is not in the code.

Possible reasons:

- `app/code/community/Msn/Resque/Model/Job/Logmessage.php` is not readable. Please double check permissions and owner.
- Opcode cache (like APC) is in place and not up to date. Flush it.
- You use the Magento compiler. Recompile, or better, disable it entirely.

Explanation why you are looking in the wrong direction:

1. The code is called from a Magento controller, and `Mage::getSingleton('mnsresque/factory')` did not result in an error, from that I conclude:

   - the Magento autoloader works
   - the module files are in the right location
2. You get an error in `vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Resque/Job/Factory.php`, that means:

   - the 3rd party library in `vendor` can be loaded as well

Comment: I have checked the permissions and confirmed that the folder has 777.Compiler is disabled by default and there is no cache.

Comment: Resque is symlinked to Vendor folder

Comment: Are you sure that's the case @nikhil? `"magento-deploystrategy":"copy"` should prevent it from symlinking, which is the default behavior, and might have some cleanup tasks that aren't expected behavior. It likely won't solve the problem but, have to attempted to install the plugin without that line?